# Android custom view should extend AppCompatTextView

Tags: android

I created simple custom view which that extended from `TextView`, in Android Studio i get this wanrning

```
This custom view should extend android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView instead
```

and i can't use `clickable` propertise, for example:

```
   <com.myapp.test.Widgets.FontAwesome
       android:layout_width="60dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
       android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:clickable="@{()->presenter.clickOnSend()}"
       android:text="@string/font_icon_post_message"
       android:textColor="@color/gray_text_color"
       android:textSize="40sp"/>
```

i get this error for `clickable` propertise:

```
Error:(91, 46) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:clickable' with parameter type lambda on com.myapp.test.Widgets.FontAwesome.
```

[image]

my custom class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FontAwesome extends TextView {
    public FontAwesome(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public FontAwesome(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public FontAwesome(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/fontawesome.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: `extend android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` it is same as TextView . AppCompatTextView use to provide backwards compatibility for new functions to older versions of Android.

Comment: thois is not a problem, you can extend whatever you want. Android Studio only warns you that AppCompatTextView is more suitable to be used for compatibility.

Comment: the code will still run ....it is a warning only

Comment: is databinding enabled ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**UPDATE:** If you're using **androidx libraries** instead of the (legacy) v7 support libraries (*which you ought to do so now...*), please use this instead:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView;
```

---

**OLD ANSWER:** (still useful if you've not migrated to androidx yet...)

> This custom view should extend
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView instead

It's a `Warning`, not an Error.

**Instead of**

```
public class FontAwesome extends TextView
```

**You should use [AppCompatTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextView.html)**

```
public class FontAwesome extends AppCompatTextView
```

Comment: Why? Can you please explain why one is good and the other one is not.

Comment: So, if we don't need any backgroundTint nor autoSize feature, we can still extend a customView from TextView, right?

Comment: @KimiChiu Yes but it is a better practice to use AppCompatTextView, so that if you decide to release the view online or if you want to use any of the new attributes

Answer (score 2):

I was with a similar problem but it's fixed. It is probably you only see the result on execution time the first time. I didn't test to rebuild project again without launch the app.

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
 import android.util.AttributeSet;

 public class CustomTxtView extends AppCompatTextView {

    public CustomTxtView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTxtView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTxtView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        setText("Hello World");
        setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }

}
```