# How to extend the Button class in Android?

Tags: java, android, class, android-widget, extends

I'm trying to extend the `Button` class in Android. I have a `flicker.java` and a `MainActivity.java`. I want to extend the Button class and add a method like `public void flicker_with_current_color(){}` to it so that I can use `flicker.flicker_with_current_color();` in the `MainActivity.java`. Unfortunately, Android Studio gives me the error (as a hint):

> This custom view should extend androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton instead

What I want to do is add a custom method so I can use it everywhere. I know it can be done by creating a method in `MainActivity.java` but I'm trying to make a custom Button class that is the same as Android's `Button` class but with more methods. I have no idea where I'm wrong.

`flicker.java`:

```java
package com.its.me;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.Timer;

public class flicker extends Button{

    public flicker(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void flicker_with_current_color(Button btn, String color_to_flicker, String color_to_switch_back_to, int time_interval, int times_to_flicker){

        for(int i=0; i<times_to_flicker; i++){

            btn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color_to_flicker));

            Timer t = new java.util.Timer();
            t.schedule(
                    new java.util.TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            btn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color_to_switch_back_to));

                            t.cancel();
                        }
                    },
                    time_interval
            );

        }
    }

    public void flicker_with_current_color(String color_to_flicker, String color_to_switch_back_to, int time_interval, int times_to_flicker){

        for(int i=0; i<times_to_flicker; i++){

            this.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color_to_flicker));

            Timer t = new java.util.Timer();
            t.schedule(
                    new java.util.TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            //this.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color_to_switch_back_to));

                            t.cancel();
                        }
                    },
                    time_interval
            );

        }
    }

    public void flicker_with_current_color(Button btn, int total_time, int times_to_flicker, String color_to_flicker, String color_to_switch_back_to){

        int time_interval = total_time/times_to_flicker;

        for(int i=0; i<times_to_flicker; i++){

            btn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color_to_flicker));

            Timer t = new java.util.Timer();
            t.schedule(
                    new java.util.TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            btn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color_to_switch_back_to));

                            t.cancel();
                        }
                    },
                    time_interval
            );

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `This custom view should extend androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton instead` - it just a warning, but it would be better to use the `AppCompat` version of `Button` for backwards compatibility. Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246336/android-custom-view-should-extend-appcompattextview). And when it comes to the `flicker` button - what is the expected behavior entirely, does the code that You provided work? If not, then what is happening? Please improve Your question.

Comment: @sweak, thanks a lot! Sorry for the late reply. The code doesn't work. The app crashes when I click the button. I just wanted to add some functions to the button but I'm not able to use them in the MainActivity.java. I want the ExtendedButton to flicker for the time and to the color in its parameters, like `ExtendedButton.flicker_with_current_color(...);`. In the XML, I want to add it like Android's Button class, like `<ExtendedButton.../>`. In the question, the flicker class is the ExtendedButton. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First You have to keep in mind, that You will need additional, overloaded constructors. The most important one is the one in which You provide XML attributes `attrs` - without it the button won't be even possible to create. You can use this set of constructors in Your code and it would be fine:

```java
public FlickerButton(Context context) {
    super(context, null, android.R.attr.buttonStyle);
}

public FlickerButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, android.R.attr.buttonStyle);
}

public FlickerButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
```

Second issue that might arise in Your code is `CalledFromWrongThreadException`. As You set a timer with its task in a different thread, Android will complain that the view, in this case our `FlickerButton`, was being manipulated on a different thread than the one that created it:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

For that I would change the approach of that *flickering* animation. Instead of using the timer I would use `ValueAnimator` to animate the color flickering. Analyze the code carefully:

```java
private int buttonTextColor = Color.BLACK; // Initially we will set the color to black
private ValueAnimator flickerAnimation; // Animator that will animate between the colors

public void flicker_with_current_color(String colorToFlicker, String colorToSwitchBackTo, int timeInterval, int timesToFlicker) {

    // Animator will animate from the colorToSwitchBackTo 
    // through colorToFlicker and back to the colorToSwitchBackTo
    flickerAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(
            Color.parseColor(colorToSwitchBackTo),
            Color.parseColor(colorToFlicker),
            Color.parseColor(colorToSwitchBackTo)
    );

    // The duration of one animation interval and how many times teh animation will repeat
    flickerAnimation.setDuration(timeInterval).setRepeatCount(timesToFlicker);

    // Specify what will happen when the animated value will change
    flickerAnimation.addUpdateListener(valueAnimator -> {
        buttonTextColor = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

        // invalidate() will invalidate the view and in turn call the onDraw() method
        invalidate();
    });

    flickerAnimation.start(); // start the animation
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    setTextColor(buttonTextColor);
}
```

With all of that code inside a subclass of `AppCompatButton` for backwards compatibility You will be ready to use the button:

```java
public class FlickerButton extends AppCompatButton {

    // Insert all the code from above here

}
```

In the XML file:

```xml
<com.example.flickerbutton.FlickerButton
        android:id="@+id/flicker_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Flicker Button" />
```

In the parent of the `FlickerButton`:

```java
((FlickerButton) findViewById(R.id.flicker_button)).setOnClickListener(view -> {
        ((FlickerButton) view).flicker_with_current_color(
                "white", "black", 500, 10);
    });
```

With all that code the button's text color will flicker for half a second 10 times through black and white color.

Now I won't leave You with just this code - I recommend You read [this](https://github.com/ZieIony/GuideToCustomViews/wiki) guide on custom views in Android to get even better understanding on what is happening in the above code and to improve Your existing projects. Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer sweak! It doesn't crash anymore but it doesn't flicker. I guess I have used it in the wrong way. [This](https://justpaste.it/2bt7p) is the FlickerButton.java with the codes from your answer. I tried using only the function you suggested but I couldn't see any change in the color of the button/its text. I then copy-pasted the function in the question but didn't work either. I then made another function but didn't work as expected.

Comment: It (the other function which I made: `changecol(...)`) only changes the color when I click it (not even for the time I keep pressing the button; only when I release it, it changes the color for a moment and then back to black). I used it in MainActivity.java like: `flickerbuttonname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Changing color now.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        flickerbuttonname.changecol("#00ff00");
    }
});`. 

Have I implemented it correctly? Again, thanks :D

Comment: You would have to show me, how You have used the `flicker_with_current_color` function within the `onClickListener`.

Comment: Oh. In the button's onClickListener (in MainActivity.java), I've used it like: `flickerbuttonname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     @Override     public void onClick(View view) {         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Started flickering.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       flickerbuttonname.flicker_with_current_color("white", "black", 5000, 10);       } });`.

Comment: You've set the interval to 5000 miliseconds which is 5 seconds. The color transition takes that long, so there is no flicker effect. Make it 500.

Comment: Yes, but I tried it as 500 only the first time but didn't work so to check if 500 milliseconds was too short, I had changed it to 5000 milliseconds. Not only the flicker effect but I don't see any color change. Is there any way I'm doing some mistake?

Comment: Wait, very sorry. I had not commented out my onDragListener and onTouchListener when I first built it. I'm very sorry I forgot about that. I guess that was the problem and was somehow interfering with the UI and the button's events. Thanks a lot sweak :D